# Joining list with table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework with asp.net mvc3 razor. Now I have a table which represents `Countries` (like India, US) etc. And my requirement is I need to open a pop-up with the flags of all countries which I have in my database. And when user click on one flag I need to show that particular country details first and remaining as line by line in the webgrid(asp.net mvc3 razor)

So I prepared a list of "Countries" by getting all the countries from database. And I prepared another list `OrderofCountries` by adding Order(property) "1" to the which user had clicked. And from 2 to all the remaining countries. Now I need to join this list i.e "OrderofContries" with the remaining tables (from database as for the requirement). But Entity Framework raises an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Slmg.BusinessObjects.CountriesBO'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

My idea here is by using order property I can sort the data so that I can get the required data.

Can we join our prepared list with the database table in Entity Framework? How to solve my issue. Can any one please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot join list in your application with database table unless you pull all data from that table to your application by calling `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Can you give me an idea how to solve my problem.